# How to get access_token using token endpoint in the node OIDC provider

Tags: node.js, oidc-provider, node-oidc-provider

I tried to get access_token and refresh_token using authorization code flow using node oidc provider. I got auth_code. but I could not get access token and refresh token How to fix this Issue. I referred many documentation but I could not get it.

**OIDC Configuration**

```
  const oidc = new Provider('http://localhost:3000', {
  clients: [
    {
      client_id: 'foo',
      client_secret: 'bar',
      redirect_uris: ['https://jwt.io'], // using jwt.io as redirect_uri to show the ID Token contents
      response_types: ['code'],
      grant_types: ['authorization_code'],
      token_endpoint_auth_method: 'none',
    },
  ],
  cookies: {
    keys: 'secretkey'
  },
  pkce: {
    required: true
  },
});

// Heroku has a proxy in front that terminates ssl, you should trust the proxy.
oidc.proxy = true;
app.use(oidc.callback())
```

I got auth_code also

[image]

[image]

How to get access token and refresh token using node-oidc provider

Comment: Authorization code flow need a human interaction. Do you need to get the token without user consent? I mean in "background".

Comment: @JRichardsz How to get the token give some example?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your access token request is missing the PKCE code_verifier parameter.
2. your client's authentication method is set to `none`, so you're not supposed to pass any authorization header.

you can start your provider process with `DEBUG=oidc-provider:*` to get more details for these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Client but you have input "client_id", it mean you are enabling features:

```
{
    clientCredentials: { 
        enabled: true 
    }
 }
```

So you must provide `client_secret`
and in oidc-provider source I see it always check `code_verifier` so you should provide it

[image: code_verifier]